# Interaction one webview with another in Android

Tags: android, android-webview

Is it possible to make webview interaction?
In webview1 I click button and it cause some action in webview2(for example color change).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can change the url of webview loading and accordingly perform action in webview

For Example :

```
webView1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {  
  @Override  
  public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {  
    if (url.startsWith("https://")) { 
      // DO SOMETHING with webview2 ..load url dynamically or so

    }  
    return shouldOverride;  
  }  
}
```

Comment: if I have such code: `<button onclick="$('body.frame2').css('background','red');">Change BG Color for Webview 2</button>` How I must implemented **shouldOverrideUrlLoading** method?

Comment: Above methods tell u the url of current page : for example in in above code if u click on button it will redirect to some page and if u know that url then u can catch that url and compare as shown in above code and do appropriat things on webview 2